# Custom icon in TabPanel fails

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to add a custom icon to a TabPanel but when I do that it just shows a dark box with rounded corners.

My css looks like this: http://pastebin.org/447682

The code in the url is base64 for some random rss icon I found on the web.
I also tried to add a relative url to an image but without any success.

If I change my code to use a base64 from the ext-touch.css file ( http://pastebin.org/447685 ) it works all fine, so why wouldn't it accept my 'custom' icon?

Note: I don't need an rss icon. I just tried that for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MrSoundless — I worked on the theming engine in Sencha Touch. The problem is that the bottom tabs use WebKit masks for icons, not traditional background images. This allows us to fill the *shape* of the icon you pass, so we can dynamically change its color on selection. To get a traditional image in there, use `background-image` instead of `-webkit-mask-box-image`. Base64 encoding as you are should still be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, except that when the selector is on the image, it hides the complete image instead of 'shining through'

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify that comment a bit? I thought we were discussing using the selector on the img.

Answer (score 0):

for example in your .html file

```
 .image{
-webkit-mask-box-image: url('/public/images/btn.png');
}
```

and use the above defined image in your tabPanel

```
iconCls: 'image',
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked in 2010, it still came up when I was searching for a solution.  This functionality seems to have changed in Sencha 2.0, and I spent a while fighting it, so here is what is needed for 2.0 compatibility:

**CSS/inline stylesheet**

```
.x-tab .x-button-icon.XXXXX,
.x-button .x-button-icon.x-icon-mask.XXXXX {
  -webkit-mask-image: url('/img/1.png');
}
```

**App.js tab panel definition**

```
{
    title: 'Your tab title',
    iconCls: 'XXXXX'
}
```

Where XXXXX is the name of your custom icon.

Hope that helps.